# Why doesn't C++ use operator== instead of operator!= automatically

Tags: c++

I understand C++ can't define `operator==` automatically for a class, but why can't it use `!(a == b)` for `a != b` when `operator!=` isn't available but `operator==` is?

I'm aware of `std::rel_ops` although I hadn't heard of it before today.

Comment: Because it only works for binary logic, not in ternary logic: True, False, File-Not-Found.

Comment: because `!=` doesn't *have to be* the opposite of `==`. Why would the compiler guess that and might make a wrong decision?

Comment: You can even return a string from `operator==`. (i.e. it's return type does not have to be `bool`)

Comment: You can use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) to automatically add operators which can be inferred from others to your class.

Comment: I considered closing this as not constructive, as it seems a bit ranty and whiney.  But if you take the ranty-ness away, this is a legitimate question that can be answered.  You may stem the tide of close votes if you can edit the question to be a little more objective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `operator==` does not necessarily mean the opposite of `operator!=`.

I cannot think of any instance where `operator==` would not mean `!operator!=`, but they are separate operators.  One of the most liberating and, at times, most frustrating things about C++ is that C++ applies a minimal set of restrictions about how you can write your code.  If you have an instance where `operator==` is not the opposite of `operator!=`, then you should be able to express that in C++.  And, in fact, you can.

You take the good with the bad in C++.  You may consider this to be in the set of "the bad".

Bear in mind that in the vast majority of cases, it is trivial to correctly implement `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`.

```
bool Gizmo::operator!=(const Gizmo& rhs) const
{
  return !operator==(rhs);
}
```

Comment: For the brave ones: `template<typename T> bool operator!=(T const& rhs, T const& lhs) { return !(rhs == lhs); }`

Comment: I know I shouldn't edit posts for a typo, but "seperate" should be "separate"..

Comment: Automatically using == instead of != if != isn't available doesn't stop you from defining != if it's not the opposite of ==, does it?

Comment: @XTF: Correct, but the point is C++ would rather not risk introducing bugs without you knowing unless there's good reason. Because it's so simple to define your own `operator!=`, there's not a good reason to take the risk. Other languages like Haskell do what you want: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Eq.

Comment: @Default Actually, you should just edit the post and fix the typo.

Comment: @Default:  Editing posts for typos is fine.  I make plenty of tpyos, so just follow me around and you'll get plenty of opportunity.

Answer (score 5):

C++ as a language does not provide functionality that you do not explicitly ask for.  I know that this philosophy is a little broken with default constructors and the like, but it was a design decision that Stroustrup made very early on - *You don't pay for what you don't use*.  So the compiler won't automatically generate something that you didn't ask for.

There is a reference to an email chain from Bjarne in early 1993 [on the ACCU web site](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1356) that includes a mention of this.  It is also in the D&E if I recall correctly; I don't have a copy of it handy to reference.

Comment: As you mention, there are exceptions.  Those exceptions are minimal.

Comment: Sometimes I wish that there were fewer exceptions, but the minimalistic intent is definitely there.

Comment: IMO "You don't pay for what you don't use" doesn't apply as I did ask/use for != and the cost is probably zero.

Comment: @XTF you asked for the functionality, but did not provide it.  The result was essentially a lookup error. This is not one of the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

The language is not allowed to do what you want. `operator==` and `operator!=` are two different operators. I can't think of an example where `!(x==y)` and `x!=y` would yield different results, but consider `operator<=` vs `operator>`. Why do you need both of these? One could write `x<=y` as `!(x>y)`, right? Wrong.

```
#include<iostream>

int main () {
   double y = 0.0;
   double x = y/y;

   std::cout << " (x <= y) -> " << (x <= y) << "\n";
   std::cout << "!(x >  y) -> " << !(x > y) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @MatthieuM. - Me too. I tend to configure the floating point environment so that `NaN` or `Inf` raise a floating point exception.

Comment: I thought about operator< etc, that issue seemed clearer.

Comment: Minor edit: your closing brace is outside the code block.

Answer (score 1):

The first version of C++ (aka C++03 after corrections) introduced the automatic definition of default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor in order to be able to compile C in C++.

It's been proven since that it may not have been the best choice though, many people who provide a custom definition for a destructor forget to define the copy constructor and assignment operator and end up with a mess on their lap.

Implicit methods, like hidden paths of execution, seem to confuse developers. And we've all been bitten I think.

---

C++11 however has a very clever mechanism for on-demand default methods:

```
class Test { Test() = default; }; // a rather useless class...
```

So, taking the lessons of C++03 automatic generation of constructors & co, I would not favor the introduction of this auto-generation, but would definitely support:

```
bool operator!=(Test const&, Test const&) = default;
```

(with `operator==` in scope, obviously)

and similarly:

```
bool operator>(Test const&, Test const&) = default;
bool operator<=(Test const&, Test const&) = default;
bool operator>=(Test const&, Test const&) = default;
```

(with `operator<` in scope, obviously)

---

However, we then might ask the real question: why not provide a much generic method ?

`operator==` generally is not botched up, but I have seen countless broken implementations of `operator<`. Apparently respecting a weak-order is not as easy as it seems (*). Still, if you think tuples, it's just a lexicographical comparison of two tuples, really!

(*) *You have implementations of `==` and `<` that do not match up (ie normally `!(a < b) and !(b < a)` <=> `a == b`), but tuples do solve that!*

Actually:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string const&> to_tuple(Test const&);
```

could be used to generate the initial operators generally:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator==(T const& left, T const& right) -> decltype(to_tuple(left), bool{}) {
    return to_tuple(left) == to_tuple(right);
}

template <typename T>
auto operator<(T const& left, T const& right) -> delctype(to_tuple(right), bool{}) {
    return to_tuple(left) < to_tuple(right);
}
```

So, what's the trap ? Well, ADL. When those templates live in a different namespace than the class you implement `to_tuple` for, then things fall apart because they are not automatically picked up by ADL (same reason while `using std::swap` is so common...).

So, then, we could argue that `bool operator==(Test const&, Test const&) = default;` should do the right thing (tm) if `to_tuple(Test const&)` is in scope. It would not even be crazy. Not too much.

However, see how far I went from the original proposal ? Imagine what a committee decision ends up being...

---

And in the mean time ?

Well, personally, I implement:

```
#define MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_, Op_)                       \
    inline bool operator Op_ (Type_ const& left, Type_ const& right) {  \
        return to_tuple(left) Op_ to_tuple(right);                      \
    }                                                                   \

#define MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_EQUAL(Type_)                                    \
    MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_, ==)                            \
    MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_, !=)

#define MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_COMP(Type_)                                     \
    MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_,  <)                            \
    MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_,  >)                            \
    MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_, <=)                            \
    MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_OPERATOR_IMPL(Type_, >=)
```

And then:

```
class Test;

std::tuple<int, std::string const&> to_tuple(Test const&); // or boost::tuple

MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_EQUAL(Test);
MY_DEFINE_TUPLE_COMP(Test);
```

It works with ADL, it generates inline code around `to_tuple` (which may or not be inline itself), it generates correct and consistent `==` and `<` implementations and it's less typing than the `= default` for all 6 methods.

Even leaves a source location behind for compiler error messages!

So... why indeed complicate the language further ?

Comment: Implicit generation of copy constructor and assignment operator is fine in general, except when a destructor is defined. It's not the implicit generation that confuses people, it's just that the choice for when to generate them isn't right. I hope compilers warn for this case, though.

Comment: @XTF: They generally don't, neither gcc nor clang AFAIK. You are right that without the destructor, it would be alright. C++11 has taken this approach, the exact terms are complicated but defining a destructor make the move constructor and move assignment operator `deleted` unless you create one yourself. It is clever ;)